# Simple way to handle letter and number combination

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Let's say I have two strings:

```
string_ex1 = 'AbC024'
string_ex2 = 'aBc24'

string_ex3 = 'AbC24'
string_ex4 = 'aBc24'
```

And I want a result that the two strings are equal if I compare each other.
For example 'AbC' == 'aBc', '024' == '24'

I already know if I distinguish them with \w+ and \d+ and convert to lowercase and to int respectively, I can get a result saying two strings are identical. But I want to know if there's some simpler function to do it.

```
string1_str = lower(re.findall('\w+', string_ex1))
string1_int = int(re.findall('\d+', string_ex1))
string2_str = lower(re.findall('\w+', string_ex2))
string2_int = int(re.findall('\d+', string_ex2))

if string1_str == string2_str and string1_int == string2_int:
    print('identical')
```

*Edit
The comparison should work both for string_ex1, string_ex2 and string_ex3, string_ex4

Comment: So, to be more precise, you want to ignore case  and leading zeros?

Comment: Could you share the code you are using right now to do the task? That will make it easier to define "simpler" :-)

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes. exactly

Comment: When you reply to a comment asking for clarification it’s generally best to edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments. Consider changing your title to, "Comparing two strings when ignoring case and leading zeroes".

Comment: One approach is to split each string into two parts with the regular expression `(?<=\D)(?=\d)`. For example, `ABC012` and `abc12` would by split into `["ABC", "012"]` and `["abc", "12"]`, respectively. Then compare `"ABC"` and `"abc"` case-independently, and compare `12` with `12` after having converted `"012"` and `"12"` to integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regex that removes leading zeros, then use [`casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) comparison:

```
import re

string_ex1 = 'AbC024'
string_ex2 = 'aBc24'

string_ex1 = re.sub(r'(?<=\D)0+(?=\d)', '', string_ex1)
string_ex2 = re.sub(r'(?<=\D)0+(?=\d)', '', string_ex2)

print(string_ex1.casefold() == string_ex2.casefold())
# True
```

Alternatively, you can call `lower` on both strings when calling `re.sub`:

```
import re

string_ex1 = 'AbC024'
string_ex2 = 'aBc24'

string_ex1 = re.sub(r'(?<=\D)0+(?=\d)', '', string_ex1.lower())
string_ex2 = re.sub(r'(?<=\D)0+(?=\d)', '', string_ex2.lower())

print(string_ex1 == string_ex2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do it. I'd suggest that for both strings you find the groups : only letters, or only digits and compare them in lower case and without leading zeros

```
def test(str1, str2):
    values1 = re.findall("([a-z]+|[0-9]+)", str1, flags=re.I)
    values2 = re.findall("([a-z]+|[0-9]+)", str2, flags=re.I)
    clean = lambda x: x.lower().lstrip("0")
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(map(clean, values1), map(clean, values2)))

print(test('AbC024', 'aBc24'))  # True
```